Copy data from Azure Storage account NFS file share to blob container
We have some data in an Azure storage account as an NFS file share that we would like to copy to a blob container using Azure Function.
We have looked into a few ways to do this and found AZ Copy would be the best option to achieve this (as per MS official documentation).
NFS File share doesn't support AZ Copy, Do you have any suggestions to achieve that.
I appreciate your help.
